# In Angular 4 , How to get data from router.navigate?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How to get data from `router.navigate`. I have tried following code but didn't got success.

```
    this.uid = success.uid;
    this.router.navigate(['app-view'], this.uid);
    console.log(success.uid);
```

Comment: which data you want to get from it? there isnt really a lot that you can obtain from it https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate

Comment: you could use dataservice approach to pass value when you route from component to another. Create a simple injectiable service class with a variable (as place holder) and import it in both component. you can then set value to variable in CompA and get it from other CompB. Code Snippet to this approach is not directly answering your question. You can ask separate question specifically if you'd like.

Comment: here i am passing 'this.uid'. So on app-view how I get access to uid?